# Download attachments from associated records - Community

Tags: community, case, security, attachment, customer-community

I have a community where users can raise cases, attach logs, etc. A user can be a customer or a partner - where partner doesn't always have partner community license (users with customer community license sometimes act as partners). A partner can create case, view and attach logs for themselves and even for associated accounts.

Problem is, partner users with customer community license get insufficient privilege error when trying the download attachments from associated accounts. How can I allow downloading attachments from associated accounts without providing view all permission?

OWD is private on Accounts, customer community profile has Create, Read, Edit permission (not view all, modify all).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to pony up for some more partner community licenses. A Customer Community user license isn't going to have access to other accounts through sharing.

Comment: Should a user with partner community profile have view all permission?

Comment: No. But the Partner Community License should allow sharing of accounts and attachments with the Partner User. The Customer Community License won't allow sharing of that kind to take place.